# Download link Microsoft Application Request Routing Version 2 for IIS 7

Tags: iis-7, msdn, arr

Where can download Microsoft Application Request Routing Version 2 for IIS 7? Please help me on this to downalod.

I tried to search microsoft websites and found the link to download but when I click on that link it given 404 error.

Comment: Microsoft keeps removing deprecated bits from its official download site, so don't waste your time there. IIS 7 reached end of life a long while ago and you must upgrade now.

Answer (score 0):

As I recall this link has been deprecated for a long time.
If you need ARR module just download from: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing. It could work with IIS 7.